# Can I use two differetnt IP addresses for same system

Tags: ip

I have created one Ubuntu server for online examination the IP for this is 192.168.104.3  so my clients have range within 192.168.104.1 to 192.168.104.255

this is not internet ip..

I want that same system can access internet by using 192.168.200.46  ..

so server have internet access but clients don't..!!!

Please give me answer.

Comment: Please try to explain in better detail.

Comment: I have created one server ...I want my server can have internet facility but the clients those who are connected to the server don't have this facility of internet...I use server to update the system...and I can do more...I use different ip address for server which is internet address but the clients use different ip address ..which is  internetless..

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the [edit] button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are a little confused on what a server does. Regardless, the answer to your question is, you need TWO network adapters. You could install a PCI LAN card or You can use one Ethernet and one WiFi adapter.

(technically you could create a virtual adapters, but let's stay away from that)